# How to convert hash table to CSV file on Perl?

Tags: perl, csv

I am a beginner for using perl for my scripting. Right now I have a hash table store on a variable (`$XML`) but I don't know how to convert it to a CSV file. Here is the content of the hash table.

```
$VAR1 = {
      'result' => {
                  'item' => [
                            {
                              'bootbox8_id' => '222333',
                              'site_id' => '144',
                              'key' => '0',
                              'os_version' => '3.1',
                              'switch_name' => 'switch1.name.com',
                              'type_id' => '109',
                              'mac' => {
                                       'item' => {
                                                 'content' => '00:B0:92:2C:CB:9D',
                                                 'key' => '0'
                                               }
                                     },
                              'property' => 'SALES',
                              'console' => 'console.name.com',
                              'name' => 'india2.name.com',
                              'bootbox8' => 'console.name.com',
                              'os_name' => 'LINUX',
                              'site' => 'india',
                              'manufacturer' => 'XXX',
                              'model' => 'XXX-4',
                              'id' => '1083376',                                  
                            },
                            {
                              'bootbox2_id' => '222333',
                              'site_id' => '144',
                              'key' => '1',
                              'os_version' => '3.1',
                              'switch_name' => '',
                              'type_id' => '109',
                              'mac' => {
                                       'item' => {
                                                 'content' => '00:B0:98:1B:C6:E2',
                                                 'key' => '0'
                                               }
                                     },
                              'property' => 'SALES',
                              'console' => 'console.name.com',
                              'name' => 'india1.name.com',
                              'bootbox2' => 'console.name.com',
                              'os_name' => 'LINUX',
                              'site' => 'india',
                              'manufacturer' => 'XXX',
                              'model' => 'XXX-4',
                              'id' => '1083377',                                
                            }
                          ]
                },
      'meta' => {
                'total_pages' => '1',
                'current_page' => '1',
                'per_page' => '10',
                'total' => '2'
              }
    };
```

And I would like to collect some fields on the hash table and convert to the CSV file like below.

```
india2.name.com,SALES,india,LINUX,XXX-4
india1.name.com,SALES,india,LINUX,XXX-5
```

Could you provide the detail sample so that I can learn on that?

Comment: I'll note - if it's in XML in the first place, there may be better ways to serialise the data as you parse the XML.

Comment: This could be XML::Simple output @Sobrique.

Comment: Yes, it could. Which is bad news, given that it's XML being coerced into arrays when pretty fundamentally, XML doesn't support arrays. But stuff like `XML::Twig` let you set element handlers that'll 'do things' to transpose your XML into a CSV style output.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over your data. The actual items are in `$XML->{result}->{item}`. You need to dereference using `@{  }`. Each item is a simple hashref. You can just `join` your data by using the keys you want.

```
foreach my $item ( @{$XML->{result}->{item}} ){
    say join ',', $item->{name}, $item->{property}, $item->{site}, $item->{os_name}, $item->{model};
}
```

If you want it a little shorter, use a hashref slice.

```
foreach my $item ( @{$XML->{result}->{item}} ){
    say join ',', @{$item}{qw(name property site os_name model)};
}
```

I'm asuming you know how to `open` a file for writing. If you want to do more complex stuff with CSV, use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) which is an excelent CSV handler that will take a lot of the pain away.

Check out [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more infos on how to work with references.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a simpler solution, from which you can better learn how to handle Arrays of Hashes in perl...:

```
my $XML = {
      'result' => {
                  'item' => [
                            {
                              'bootbox8_id' => '222333',
                              'site_id' => '144',
                              'key' => '0',
                              'os_version' => '3.1',
                              'switch_name' => 'switch1.name.com',
                              'type_id' => '109',
                              'mac' => {
                                       'item' => {
                                                 'content' => '00:B0:92:2C:CB:9D',
                                                 'key' => '0'
                                               }
                                     },
                              'property' => 'SALES',
                              'console' => 'console.name.com',
                              'name' => 'india2.name.com',
                              'bootbox8' => 'console.name.com',
                              'os_name' => 'LINUX',
                              'site' => 'india',
                              'manufacturer' => 'XXX',
                              'model' => 'XXX-4',
                              'id' => '1083376',
                            },
                            {
                              'bootbox2_id' => '222333',
                              'site_id' => '144',
                              'key' => '1',
                              'os_version' => '3.1',
                              'switch_name' => '',
                              'type_id' => '109',
                              'mac' => {
                                       'item' => {
                                                 'content' => '00:B0:98:1B:C6:E2',
                                                 'key' => '0'
                                               }
                                     },
                              'property' => 'SALES',
                              'console' => 'console.name.com',
                              'name' => 'india1.name.com',
                              'bootbox2' => 'console.name.com',
                              'os_name' => 'LINUX',
                              'site' => 'india',
                              'manufacturer' => 'XXX',
                              'model' => 'XXX-4',
                              'id' => '1083377',
                            }
                          ]
                },
      'meta' => {
                'total_pages' => '1',
                'current_page' => '1',
                'per_page' => '10',
                'total' => '2'
              }
    };

foreach my $item (@{$XML->{result}->{item}}) {
  for $key ( keys %{ $item } ) {
    if (grep( /^$key$/, qw(name property site os_name model))) {
      print $XML->{'result'}->{'item'}->[$i]{$key} . ",";
    }
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

Which produces:

```
india2.name.com,SALES,india,LINUX,XXX-4,
india1.name.com,SALES,india,LINUX,XXX-5,
```

Comment: How would the `grep` with a regular expression be more simple? It might make sense if you don't know if all the keys are there, but then the concatenation will lead to inconsistent CSV data. Also the comma at the end is wrong, because it introduces an additional empty column to the CSV file.